# stopping the ajax before send image

Tags: jquery, ajax

please how do i stop the beforeSend image ater submitting a form through ajax method. here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<form id="my-form">
    <input type="test" id="post" name="post" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="post" class="slide" />
</form><div id="tutorial"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#my-form').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: "fell.php",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $('#tutorial').html("<img src='progress-dots.gif' />");
                },
                success: function(status) {
                    $('#post').val('');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can add a unique class on that loader image and after ajax completion, remove that image loader.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#my-form').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: "fell.php",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $('#tutorial').html("<img class='custom-progress-dots' src='progress-dots.gif' />");
                },
                complete: function(){
                    $('.custom-progress-dots').remove();
                },
                success: function(status) {
                    $('#post').val('');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

In the above code jQuery **complete** callback is used to make sure loader is removed in both cases when ajax calls successfully completes or get error.

Answer (score 0):

if your goal is to remove the image after the ajax call returns successfully, then set the html empty in the `success` callback function:

```
            success: function(status) {
                $('#post').val('');
                $('#tutorial').html("");
            }
```

thanks **@Jeromy French** for pointing out that annoying spinner that always leaves you hanging on failure. you should throw an error message in there to help your users out when having technical difficulties.

```
            success: function(status) {
                $('#post').val('');
                $('#tutorial').html("");
            },
            error: function() {
                $('#tutorial').html("sorry! there was an error");
            }
```

Comment: What if AJAX load fails? You'd still show the "thumper", giving the user the mistaken impression that they should still wait on the system.